# override dependency inversion laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

i have `RequestInterface.php` like this :

```
    <?PHP
namespace App\Http\Requests;

interface RequestInterface {

}
```

and abstract class `Request.php` :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;


abstract class Request extends FormRequest implements RequestInterface {

    //
}
```

and i have `PagesRequest.php` that extends from `Request.php` :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Helpers\Helpers;

class PageRequest extends Request implements RequestInterface  {
```

In controller i have to inject PageRquest and override `edit()` method of `CrudController` class and check injection in another class like this :

PageController.php :

```
protected function update( $id, PageRequest $request){
    parent::update( $request, $id);
}
```

and file that i have to check injected class to have RequestInterface :

```
   protected function update($id, RequestInterface $request)
    {
}
```

But i have this error

> Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::update() should
>   be compatible with
>   App\Http\Controllers\MasterController\CrudController::update($id,
>   App\Http\Requests\RequestInterface $request)

Parent class `Request` implements `RequestInterface` and `PageRequest` extended with `Request` so `PageRequest` have `RequestInterface` interface but i i get this error.

Answer (score 1):

You have swapped the arguments of the update method. The method in the parent class expects the $request object in the second argument slot -  you pass it to the first when you call it from within the subclass.